# How to show a message with the selected items with a Bootstrap Select List C# ASP .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to know a way to show an alert with all the selected items after pressing a button, could be with the code behind or jQuery, any of them work, this is a sample:

```
<label for="sel2">Mutiple select list (hold shift to select more than one):</label>
      <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel2">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
      </select>
```

The output should be a regular alert with all the selected items, thanks in advance.

(Edit: Wrong sample)

Answer (score 1):

HTML :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="sel1" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="btn">Alert Selected</button>
</div>
```

Script

```
<script>

  $("#btn").click(function(){
     alert($("#sel1").val());
  });

</script>
```